# Handling unknown number of states in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React Native project and I have a React component which displays a list of questions and their options. Let's say all questions are multiple choices, and I use a Picker for that, `DropDownPicker`. (react-native-dropdown-picker). I need a way to manage whether the picker is opened or closed. The component has 2 props, `open` and `setOpen`. There is an unknown number of questions, so I can't initialise all the states.

I've tried doing `const [open, setOpen] = useState([])`, where `open` is an array of open statuses. Here's a code snippet:

```
questions.map((v,i) => {
  setOpen([...open, false]);      // causes infinite renders

  return (
    ...
      <DropDownPicker
        open={open[i]}
        setOpen={o => {          // returns true/false
          let list = [...open];
          list[i] = o;
          return list;
        }/>
    ...
  )
}
```

The code runs into infinite renders when appending a boolean to the state at `setOpen([...open, false])`. Another way I've tried is to use a variable rather than a state variable, but that doesn't work either.

Can I check whether there's an ideal way to handle an unknown number of states?

Comment: lifted from react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#:~:text=useReducer%20is%20usually%20preferable%20to,dispatch%20down%20instead%20of%20callbacks.

the rule i follow is that the moment I use non-primitives as values of useState. I switch to useReducer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach of using a state that is an array of Booleans seems like a reasonable approach.  I would do it something like this:

```js
// Initialize to array of false, of length equal to questions
const [open, setOpen] = useState(questions.map((v) => false));
return questions.map((v,i) =>
  <DropDownPicker open={open[i]} setOpen={(o) => {
    let list = [...open];
    list[i] = o;
    setOpen(list);
  }/>
);
```

Note that `setOpen` does not immediately change `open`; rather, it schedules a change to the `open` state which happens after the render completes. This is why your code doesn't converge; every render triggers `open` to grow more.

Comment: Argh I forgot to call setOpen! Thanks a lot! Can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1):

You can manage open and close status in question array for example

```js
let question:any[] = [
{id:1, questionText:'Some text',open:false, answers:[]}
{id:2, questionText:'Some text',open:false, answers:[]}
]
```

```js
{question.forEach((item)=>{
<DropDownPicker

        open={open[i]}
        setOpen={o => {          // returns true/false
          let index = question.findIndex(id)=>id==itemid;
question[index].open = true;
}
 }/>
});
}
```